# Web Setup Project not working

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-installer

'The installer was interrupted before [project name] could be installed.  You need to restart the installer to try again.'

I just moved to Win7, and I cannot get the .msi files to install from my Web Setup Projects that are built on that machine.  The same projects build and work fine on my other Windows XP, IIS6, VS 2008 SP1 machine.  I'm not sure if this is a IIS7 or Win7 issue, but I've done the following:

1. I have all the IIS/ASP.net compatibility settings checked.
2. I am an administrator, and I have UAC turned off.

I get the following error when I even try install the .msi file on the Win7 machine and on our existing development server (windows 2003 with IIS6).

I've restarted the windows installer service, and I've added logging for the installer but there is nothing that is showing me what the problem is.  Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Does the setup succeed if you right-click and specifically install with elevated privs?

Vista's UAC was rather buggy, and sometimes would fail to elevate privileges when you had it disabled. I dunno about Win7, but it may be worth trying the counter-intuitive trick of enabling UAC and trying the install so it prompts you.

Furthermore, it seems that the old method of triggering UAC elevation that worked for Vista has changed with Win7, so you'll probably need both specified in the MSI package to be sure.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issues. 

Thakns.

Comment: Yes, by running the following command:  

'regsvr32.exe actxprxy.dll'

Answer (score 9):

I'm running Visual Studio 2005 and had the same problem as you described when moving to Windows 7.

After trying my Web Setup Project .msi file on another computer also running Windows 7 I found that it worked.

When I looked in the "Windows Features" dialog on the working computer I noticed that the IIS had IIS 6 compatibility features turned on. I enabled the same feature on my computer and after that I could install my setup project.

Open up "Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off" in Windows 7 and in the "Windows Features" dialog go to "Internet Information Services > Web Management Tools > IIS 6 Management Compatibility" and check the feature "IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility".

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer with full verbose logging:
msiexec /i  /lv installLog.txt

Then search the installLog.txt file for "Return Value 3"

This will indicate the exact problem.

Additionally this may help:
http://blog.dragonsoft.us/2009/01/02/visual-studio-2008-and-iis-7/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running 'regsvr32.exe actxprxy.dll'

It resolved the following:

1. Not able to create valid .msi web project in VS 2008.
2. Start Page in VS2008 was not displaying rss feed in the main window.
3. IE was not opening up shorted url links to a new tab (in twitter for example).

I suspect this was because of redirects, but I'm not sure.  I'm guessing this was a bug in the install process, so I hope this helps others.